# rearranging axis labels in Plotly R

Tags: r, plotly

I have the following data frame:

```
structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:7, .Label = c("Friday", "Monday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"), class = "factor"), 
    Freq = c(20938L, 43147L, 35027L, 24087L, 7148L, 6310L, 19027L
    )), .Names = c("Var1", "Freq"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks like this:

```
       Var1  Freq
1    Friday 20938
2    Monday 43147
3  Saturday 35027
4    Sunday 24087
5  Thursday  7148
6   Tuesday  6310
7 Wednesday 19027
```

when I plot it using plotly library, the x-axis starts from Wednesday and goes all the way up to Friday.  But I want to reorder the labels starting from Sunday to Saturday.  I use the following codes:

Assuming 't' is the data frame with data given above:

```
target <- c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
a <- t[match(target, t$Dayoftheweek), ]
plot_ly(a, x = Dayoftheweek, y = Freq, type = "bar", color = Dayoftheweek)
```

This doesn't work. I have reset the rownames to null still the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative would be `ggplot2`. You can try:

```
t <- factor(t$Var1, levels = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))
ggplot(data=t, aes(x=Var1, y=Freq, fill=Var1)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + theme_bw()
ggplotly()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this earlier...but I was getting an error "Error in gg2list(p) : object 'nann' not found".  But when I restarted the R session, it worked.  Couldn't understand....thanks a ton however.  I got this confirmed.